# UICollectionView indexPath.row or item, items not stable, jumping around

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a collection view and I'm loading images into it.  Problem I'm running across is when I click on a cell to get it's indexPath.item or indexPath.row, the numbers are all screwed up.  Clicking on the very first image doesn't display anything, clicking on the next will give me 0.  Clicking on the third will give me a 1, and clicking back on the second one gives me a 2.  This happens all throughout the view.  Has to be something wrong that I'm doing.  Here's my code:

viewDidLoad:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 10, 20);
[layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(75, 75)];
self.images = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 230, self.view.frame.size.width, 200) collectionViewLayout:layout];
self.images.delegate = self;
self.images.dataSource = self;
[self.images registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[self.view addSubview:self.images];
```

delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.imagesGallery.count; //image paths for server
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.imagesGallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    [cell addSubview:image];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.item);
}
```

I'm not sure how to get exact control of what goes where.  Are they numbered normally like:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
....
```

Or is there a special way they get numbered based on the sections?  How do they get populated?

Comment: Since you've got a single section, your example layout looks correct.  If you have multiple sections then each section will have that layout with empty space filling out the last "line" of the section.

Comment: You're also going to have display problems because each time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called, you add another image view to the cell without ever removing the old one.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Isn't the process the same as a table view?  What do I need to add to optimize display?

Comment: The process is "exactly" the same as with tableviews (where exactly is defined as 'for purposes of this question')  `dequeueReusableCell...` will reuse existing cells that have been scrolled off-screen.  In your case, when that happens the reused cell will already contain an image view added the last time the cell was used.  You then add a second (and a third and a fourth and...) image view when the cell is subsequently reused.

Comment: You should also be adding the image view to cell.contentView, not to cell.  Assuming you're not adding any other views to the cell, it should be sufficient to add remove all subviews from cell.contentView before adding the new image view.

Comment: Alright, I'll add that to my code.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing one delegate methods that defines how many section will your collection view have?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1; 
}
```

and one the more change the method didDeSelect for didSelect...

Comment: From the documentation: *"If you do not implement this method, the collection view uses a default value of 1."*

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  What a dumb mistake of didSelect, not didDeselect

Comment: It usually happens as the most of the delegate/datasources method have the almost same names.

Answer (score 9):

You have implemented `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:`, not `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.
Therefore selecting a cell logs the index path of the *previously* selected cell.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  All the code is starting to blend together.  I need a break.  Thanks, it's working like it should

Comment: This caught me out for ages - Xcode's autocomplete filled in didDeselect... and not didSelect...Very difficult to spot.

Comment: oh no, not that again!!